# How to set RequestBody for Http Delete method.

Tags: http, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents, http-delete

I am writing a client code for a server which Delete API. The API specification requires data to be sent. I am using HttpComponents v3.1 library for writing client code. Using the [HtpDelete](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/httpclient//class-useHttpMethod.html) class I could not find a way to add request data to it. Is there a way to do so ? Below is the code snippet.

```
        HttpDelete deleteReq = new HttpDelete(uriBuilder.toString());
    List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(RestConstants.POST_DATA_PARAM_NAME, 
            postData.toString()));
    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
        entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        //deleteReq.setEntity(entity); // There is no method setEntity()
        deleteReq.setHeader(RestConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, RestConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER_VAL);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.error("UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what API is that? (requiring a DELETE request body)

Comment: Its a custom 3rd party REST API. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tried this, and it is as hackish as hell and I wolud feel happier if it turns out there is better solution, but you might try to extend PostMetod and override getName() method to return "DELETE".

Answer (score 10):

why not do this :-)

```
class MyHttpDelete extends HttpPost{
    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "DELETE";
    }
}
```