# Delete a collection received in WEB API's DELETE endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am intending to create a DELETE end point for my .net Core WEB API solution. I will be receiving a json collection of items to be deleted. This will be received from a mobile device. In the DELETE end point how can I capture the collection of items passed. [In a similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266406/webapi-delete-list-by-httpclient) I read that DELETE does not accept a message body.

I it possible to capture the json list sent from the mobile device, in the DELETE end point?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass data in request body. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1

```
[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
{ }
```

[image: DELETE request]
[image]

Comment: I believe sending "POST" data via `HttpDelete` has undefined behavior. In the HTTP spec, it says it's not supported. In his question he linked a question about it. Here is a *heated* conversation about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request Read the comments under the accepted answer.

Comment: @Andy I think when we talk about this framework it is pretty deterministic. But thats true that it is subject to test when switching/upgrading framework for your application.

Comment: There are a lot of pitfalls -- especially since he's writing a mobile application, Android, for example, will drop the body of a `HttpDelete` causing your method to fail.